# pandas: Sum group by month from given day

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe below by day, i want to sum group by month .
How can i do it please?

```
date, Revenue, Fourniture
2021-07-01, 200, 5
2021-07-08, 300, 12
2021-08-01, 400, 10
2021-08-18, 200, 12
2021-08-30, 100, 10
2021-08-31, 400, 5
```

**Expected output**

```
2021-07, 500, 17
2021-08, 1400, 47
```

Comment: For August 37 not 47.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by year-month by [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and take the sum by [`.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum).

As you want the date string as `YYYY-mm` in the output, you can use the formatted date string as the Grouper directly. Get the date string by using [`dt.strftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html).

```
# convert to datetime format if not already in datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df.groupby(df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')).sum().reset_index()
```

Result:

```
      date  Revenue  Fourniture
0  2021-07      500          17
1  2021-08     1100          37
```